# Maven: Build exploded ear only

Tags: maven, ear, exploded

My build currently uses `maven-ear-plugin` to create an ear as an folder (exploded) and an archive.
I only use the exploded version for development.

The archive is large and to reduce build duration, I would like to skip the creation of the archive, and generate only the exploded version.

Similar can be done for maven-war-plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/exploded-mojo.html

How can I do the same for ear?

Comment: I think maven-ear-plugin already create extracted folder in target .. you may check and confirm back

Comment: I edited to clarify the question. Indeed by default maven-ear-plugin builds a folder and an archive.
The idea here is to skip the compression step (`[INFO] Building jar: .../app.ear`)